# Crowdflower: how to include custom HTML?

Tags: javascript, mechanicalturk, crowdsourcing, crowdflower

I am trying to create a job on Crowdflower with its Builder tool. So far so good. I have items of text that I want people to label:

```
a string with some <b>html</b> elements, such as <p> and <br>
```

When I include {{text}} in the Crowdflower Builder, instead of showing the text in bold or with extra linebreaks, it literally shows me the html tags. I had a look at the HTML page source that is created by the Builder, it seems that somewhere in the Crowdflower pipeline all my HTML tags are converted to

```
 a string with some &lt;b&gt;html&lt;/b&gt; elements, such as &lt;p&gt; and &lt;br&gt;
```

Is there a way to get around this restriction? I really need the custom HTML tags for my job. There is an option to include your own CSS and Javascript in a job, and my last resort would be to write a Javascript function that unescapes my HTML tags. But I am hoping that I miss something extremely simple here.

Sorry about the misleading "Javascript" tagging, I cannot create a custom tag (which would have been crowdfower).

**EDIT:**

In case someone has the same problem: writing a custom Javascript function does actually work, I just tried it. Still hoping for a better solution though :)

Answer (score 0):

Are you still having an issue with this? It should work. I can upload a CSV with a column called text and then use {{text}} in the CML editor to display the text with bold and line breaks that you included above. Feel free to message me if you're still having trouble.

The template language is a subset of Liquid from Shopify although it sounds like you might already be familiar with that.

Comment: I am still using my Javascript workaround - it works fine :) I need a lot of different HTML, just line breaks and bold is not enough. Thanks for the pointer to Liquid, I actually didn't know that the language was based on something like that! I'll look it up.

Comment: Since I just need some portion of the text in bold, but it has to be marked in the csv, what can I use specifically?

Comment: @shapecatcher I'm not sure what you're asking exactly. If you're trying to insert partially bolded text using a CSV, then you can create a column in the CSV (say the column name is "title") and a given row would have a value like "a string with some <b>bolded text</b>". Then you can use {{title}} in the CrowdFlower CML Editor to insert the given item's text into the page.

Answer (score 0):

In which format do you upload your data?

I had the same problem: I started with CSV, had columns messed up with bigger imports and switched to ODS-spreadsheet, which worked fine. However, ODS seems to save  tags in entity-encoding, which Crowdflower doesn't decode. Thus,  becomes "<b>", so that you cannot import html tags with ODS.

Uploading my data in JSON solved all problems and  tags work as they should, without JS work-arounds.